# How to calculate travel distance of b2body object

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my cocos2d project I have game chip on the gameboard. I use b2MouseJoint to move this chip around the board.
To move chip I use following code

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

        if (_mouseJoint == NULL) return;

        UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);
        _mouseJoint->SetTarget(locationWorld);


}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

        if (_mouseJoint != NULL) return;
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint startPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];
        b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(startPoint.x/PTM_RATIO, startPoint.y/PTM_RATIO);
        _touchedBody = [self getBodyAtLocation:locationWorld];

            if(_touchedBody != NULL)
            {
                b2MouseJointDef md;
                md.bodyA = _groundBody;
                md.bodyB = _touchedBody;
                md.target = locationWorld;
                md.collideConnected = true;
                md.frequencyHz = 4.0f;
                md.maxForce = 900000.0f * _touchedBody->GetMass();
                _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md);
                _touchedBody->SetAwake(true);

            }         


  }
```

So, I need to calculate travel distance of my _touchedBody. Please, help me.

Comment: Use `previousLocationInView:` and Pythagoras' theorem (the `hypot()` function from the C standard library, in particular).

Comment: Could have found that more quickly by googling it, I guess...

Comment: @H2CO3 if i query SO for "travel distance of object" i get this as top answer, and 4 irrelevant ones. If i query google for the same, i get 100+ irrelevant SO Q&A's, but not this one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will calculate distance not only between 2 points

in header:

```
NSMutableArray *pathPoints;
```

on init:

```
pathPoints = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
```

ccTouchesBegan:

```
[pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint]];
```

ccTouchesMoved:

```
[pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:location]];
```

ccTouchesEnded:

```
[pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:location]];

CGPoint prevPoint = CGPointZero;
float distanceOfTravel = 0;
for(NSValue *v in pathPoints)
{
    if(CGPointEqualToPoint(prevPoint, CGPointZero))
    {
        prevPoint = [v CGPointValue];
        continue;
    }

    CGPoint curPoint = [v CGPointValue];
    distanceOfTravel += ccpDistance(prevPoint, curPoint);
}
NSLog(@"Distance:%f",distanceOfTravel);
[pathPoints removeAllObjects];
```

dealloc:

```
[pathPoints release];
```

Comment: Vitaly, thank you for your reply. I found your answer useful for me. But I think, that array is not necessary in this case. Enough to declare in header distanceOfTravel variable and store previous point.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the location of the object when ccTouchesBegan is called, and then use the final position after ccTouchesMoved is finished to compute the difference.